# Error converting from a .htm to .aspx file

Tags: asp.net, vbscript

I swapped my index.htm to default.aspx which contains some vbscript but for some odd reason it worked as a .htm but as an .aspx page is gives me this error:

```
BC30289: Statement cannot appear within a method body. End of method assumed.
```

Is there a quick simple fix for this? or do I have to reprogram my vbscript to work around C# or VB? Any ideas?

Comment: It would probably help to see your code...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your vbscript is meant to be client-side, the change to .aspx might be running the vbscript as server code instead of client-side code. Try putting the vbscript in a script element:

```
<script>
' vbscript code...
</script>
```

If you *do* want the VB to run on the server instead of the client, make sure you are not declaring another function within the Page_Load() function. You can't declare a function within a function.

It would also be helpful to see your code.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check that your code is placed properly within your .aspx page.

```
<script runat="server" language="vb">

</script>
```